# In Ethereum blockchain does smart contract can have token balance

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

In Ethereum we have 2 different types of account  Externally owned accounts (EOAs) and Contract accounts . EOA's  can have balance of ether and tokens . smart contract can have balance of ether,  but can they have balance of tokens?
I have created ERC 20 token , can i send this tokens to other smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, smart contracts can receive and send tokens as a normal accounts.

There is mapping which is usually called `balances` in token smart contract (ERC20). It looks like `address => uint balance` where `address` has the same format both for account and smart contract addresses (basicaly `address` is just a sequence of 20 bytes in hexadecimal; *P.S. format is the same, but the way they are calculated is different!*).

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: I sent tokens from ERC20 contract to another simple contract (Sample), In that sample contract i wrote a function to return balance , 
    function balance() constant returns(uint256){
        address sd=this;
        return sd.balance;
    } The function is not displaying balance of tokens? is address.balance only for ether not for tokens?

Comment: @user3209324 in ERC20 basic token there already is `function balanceOf(address _owner)`. It returns `balances[_owner]`.

Comment: I sent ERC20 token Contract A to B, In B i am trying to get balance of B , Is it wrong way to do that.

Comment: You should watch balance in contract A. I think you don’t understand that all tokens are located in one contract. So basically token holders are all in one mapping. They are not literally “sending”.

Comment: Thanks i understood it